# alter pom file for heroku deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, heroku, pom.xml

I'm trying to deploy an Eclipse jee dynamic web app to heroku.  I need to modify the pom file but I'm not sure how.

Here's what I need to add but I'm not sure where to place:

```
<configuration>
   <appName>gentle-shore-6874</appName>
</configuration>
```

here's the file from eclipse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildpacks>
            <buildpack>heroku/exec</buildpack>
            <buildpack>heroku/metrics</buildpack>
            <buildpack>heroku/jvm</buildpack>
          </buildpacks>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        <configuration>

           <appName>gentle-shore-6874</appName>

          <buildpacks>
            <buildpack>heroku/exec</buildpack>
            <buildpack>heroku/metrics</buildpack>
            <buildpack>heroku/jvm</buildpack>
          </buildpacks>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```